# Worth adding a webserver?

Tags: android, spring, mongodb, arduino

I'm conducting a small project using the arduino uno. I will be connecting a wifi module and a gps module to the arduino and transferring the latitude and longitude over to a web server in which it will store the records to a database. Initially, I was planning on using Spring Web as the web server (for the url routing, request path etc) and mongodb as the database storage but upon further research, it looks like the arduino can act as a web server (pretty much send a HTTP POST method to the database). So I'm confused whether or not I should include Spring Web. I will also build an android app which will communicate and query the database.

In terms of efficiency and ease, which tech stack would be advisable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can spring web as new feature of spring supporting the android development please refer this http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/ for further assistance.